# Sorting an object in an array through a method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, methods

This function sorts an array. First, the objects in which the country is equal to the one specified in the second argument should be displayed. Then all the rest. But I can not understand what is wrong?

```js
 
const arr = [
  {  
"name":"BMW",
"price":"55 000",
"country":"Germany",
"certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
"name":"Mitsubishi",
"price":"93 000", 
"constructor":"Bar John",
"door":"3",
"country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
"name":"Mercedes-benz",
"price":"63 000", 
"country":"Germany",
"certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
"name":"TOYOTA", 
"price":"48 000", 
"max_people":"7",
"country":"Japan",
"certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
"name":"Volkswagen",
"price":"36 000", 
"constructor":"Pier Sun",
"country":"Germany",
"certificate":"no"
  },
 ];

 function countries(arr,country){
  let one =  arr.sort(function(item){
return country > item.country;
  });
  return one;
}

console.log(countries(arr,"Japan"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare both object with the wanted country and move this items to top.

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) mutates the order of the array.

```js
function countries(array, country) {
    return array.sort(({ country: a }, { country: b }) => (b === country) - (a === country));
}

const array = [{ name: "BMW", price: "55 000", country: "Germany", certificate: "yes" }, { name: "Mitsubishi", price: "93 000", constructor: "Bar John", door: "3", country: "Japan" }, { name: "Mercedes-benz", price: "63 000", country: "Germany", certificate: "yes" }, { name: "TOYOTA", price: "48 000", max_people: "7", country: "Japan", certificate: "yes" }, { name: "Volkswagen", price: "36 000", constructor: "Pier Sun", country: "Germany", certificate: "no" }];

console.log(countries(array, "Japan"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer ! I have the same problem. For IE compatibility, I adapt your code to : `return array.sort(function(a, b) { return (b.country === country) - (a.country === country));`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `sort`'s callback takes two parameters, and change your sort logic slightly:

```js
 

const arr = [
  {  
"name":"BMW",
"price":"55 000",
"country":"Germany",
"certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
"name":"Mitsubishi",
"price":"93 000", 
"constructor":"Bar John",
"door":"3",
"country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
"name":"Mercedes-benz",
"price":"63 000", 
"country":"Germany",
"certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
"name":"TOYOTA", 
"price":"48 000", 
"max_people":"7",
"country":"Japan",
"certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
"name":"Volkswagen",
"price":"36 000", 
"constructor":"Pier Sun",
"country":"Germany",
"certificate":"no"
  },
 ];

 function countries(arr,country){
  let one =  arr.sort(function(a, b){
return a == country ? -1 : b == country ? 1 : 0;
  });
  return one;
}

console.log(countries(arr,"Japan"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The compare function in `Array.sort` should return:

- value > 0 to present a > b
- value < 0 to present a < b
- value == 0 to present a == b

So the easiest way is to change it to:

```
let one = arr.sort(function(item) {
    return (country > item.country) ? 1 : -1
});
```